# Refining Rudin's proof of $\lim \left (1+\frac 1 n\right)^n =\lim \sum_{k=1}^n \frac {1}{k!}$.

Tags: real-analysis

In PoMA Rudin writes

> Let $s_n=\sum_0^n \frac 1 {k!}$, $t_n=\left(1+\frac 1 n \right)^n$.

> By the binomial theorem, $$t_n=1+1+\frac{1}{2!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) + \frac{1}{3!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) +\cdots+\frac 1 {n!}\left(1-\frac 1 n\right)\left(1-\frac 2 n\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac {n-1} n\right).$$

> Hence $t_n\leq s_n$, so that $\limsup t_n\leq e$.

> Next, if $n\geq m$,

> $$
> t_n\geq 1+1+\frac 1 {2!}\left(1-\frac 1 n\right)+\cdots \frac 1 {m!}\left(1-\frac 1 n\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac {m-1} n\right).
> $$

> Keeping $m$ fixed and letting $n\to \infty$. We get
> $$\liminf t_n \geq 1+1+\frac 1 {2!}+\cdots \frac {1}{m!}.$$

> So that $s_m\leq \liminf t_n$. Letting $m\to \infty$ we get that $e\leq \liminf t_n$.

I'd like to remove all the $\,\cdots$'s as I'm a bit allergic to them (first to justify the claim that $t_n\leq s_n$, and then the "if  $n\geq m$ then..." part).

I couldn't do this myself, so I ask for your help. Thanks!

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/54499) might be useful.

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254335/prove-that-5-2-e-3/254339#254339

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It wouldn't have killed Rudin to write a few more details in this proof. I don't like writing in my books, but I finally broke down and wrote a few lines of explanation in my copy, after my second or third experience of looking up this proof and forgetting why it worked.

---

The structure of the proof is to show that
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty}t_n \leq e \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty}t_n$$
Since we always have $\liminf \leq \limsup$, the above inequality implies that 
$$\liminf_{n \to \infty}t_n = \limsup_{n \to \infty}t_n = e$$
and therefore the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}t_n$ exists and equals $e$.

---

The first step is to prove that
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty}t_n \leq e$$

A minor detail: you have miscopied slightly. Comparing with Rudin, your term 
$$\frac{1}{2!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right)$$
should instead be these two terms:
$$\frac{1}{2!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) + \frac{1}{3!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right)$$
Let us see how to obtain an expression without ellipses:
$$\begin{aligned}
t_n &= \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k} 1^{n-k} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{k}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\left(\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n-j)\right)\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^k \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\left(\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{n-j}{n}\right) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\left(\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(1 - \frac{j}{n}\right)\right) \\
\end{aligned}$$
In the last line, note that the $j=0$ term in the product is $1$, which is why Rudin only needs to write $k-1$ factors of the form $\left(1 - \frac{j}{n}\right)$ in his $k$'th term. Also note that the $k=0$ and $k=1$ terms are simply $1$. (We use the standard convention that the empty product in the $k=0$ term, $\displaystyle\prod_{j=0}^{0-1}$, is equal to $1$.)

Since each factor $\left(1 - \frac{j}{n}\right)$ is $\leq 1$, the $k$th term in the sum is $\leq 1/(k!)$, which gives us
$$t_n \leq \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!} = s_n$$
We can take the limsup of both sides of this inequality to conclude that
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} t_n \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty} s_n = \lim_{n \to \infty}s_n = e$$

---

The next step is to show that 
$$e \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty}t_n$$
Observe that the terms in the sum 
$$t_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\left(\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(1 - \frac{j}{n}\right)\right)$$
obtained above are all nonnegative, so $t_n$ is at least as large as the sum of the first $m$ terms ($m \leq n$):
$$t_n \geq \sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{1}{k!}\left(\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(1 - \frac{j}{n}\right)\right)$$
which is the second expression given by Rudin. The right-hand side depends on both $m$ and $n$. For convenience, let's give it a name:
$$a_{m,n} = \sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{1}{k!}\left(\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(1 - \frac{j}{n}\right)\right)$$
So our inequality is simply
$$t_n \geq a_{m,n}$$
Let us now consider what happens if we hold $m$ fixed and take $n \to \infty$. We focus on the right hand side.

First, observe that $0 \leq j \leq k-1$, and $0 \leq k \leq n$, which means that $0 \leq j \leq n-1$. Therefore
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 - \frac{j}{n}\right) = 1$$
Now, observe that $m$, $j$, and $k$ do not depend on $n$, so the limit of the product is the product of the limits of the factors:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1} \left(1 - \frac{j}{n}\right) = \prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left[ \lim_{n \to \infty}  \left(1 - \frac{j}{n}\right) \right] = \prod_{j=0}^{k-1} [1] = 1$$
Similarly, the limit of the sum is the sum of the limits of the terms, so
$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{m,n} &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{1}{k!}\left(\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(1 - \frac{j}{n}\right)\right)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{1}{k!} \left[\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(1 - \frac{j}{n}\right)\right]\right) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{m} \frac{1}{k!}[1] \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{m} \frac{1}{k!} \\
&= s_m \\
\end{aligned}$$
This shows that the limit of the right hand side of the inequality
$$t_n \geq a_{m,n}$$
exists as $n \to \infty$. We don't yet know that the limit of the left hand side exists. But certainly we can take the liminf of both sides to obtain
$$\liminf_{n \to \infty}t_n \geq \liminf_{n \to \infty} a_{m,n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}a_{m,n} = s_m$$
where we have used the fact shown above that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{m,n}$ exists and equals $s_m$.
Then, as Rudin indicates, we can take the limit of the right hand side as $m \to \infty$ (the left hand side does not depend on $m$), to conclude that
$$\liminf_{n \to \infty}t_n \geq \lim_{m \to \infty}s_m = e$$
This concludes the proof.

Comment: "It wouldn't have killed Rudin to write a few more details in this proof" - heh...

Comment: @Math1000 :-) Some people would say that the same applies to all of Rudin's proofs, but I think this one is especially annoying in that regard.

Comment: I really agree :-P. One question, on the line after the $(m\leq n)$ part, why can you take $\lim_n$? After that, why does $$\lim_n \sum_{k=0}^m \frac {1}{k!}\left(\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac j n\right)\right) = \sum_{k=0}^m \frac {1}{k!}\left(\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\lim_n\left(1-\frac j n\right)\right) $$?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: I added some extra detail which will hopefully clarify things.

Comment: Excellent answer @Bungo, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Since $$t_n:=\left(\frac1n+1\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\left(\frac1n\right)^k1^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\left(\frac1n\right)^k,$$
the assertion $t_n\le s_n$ follows from the fact that
$${n!\over k!(n-k)!}\frac1{n^k}\le\frac1{k!}$$
which is a restatement of the fact
$$n!\le n^k(n-k)!.$$
As for the next step, we have for each $m$: if $n\ge m$, then
$$
t_n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\left(\frac1n\right)^k\ge\sum_{k=0}^m{n\choose k}\left(\frac1n\right)^k.\tag1
$$
The $k$th term on the RHS can be written
$$\frac1{k!}{n!\over(n-k)!}\frac1{n^k}.\tag2
$$ The assertion is that this tends to $\frac1{k!}$ as $n\to\infty$. To see this is true, set aside the $1/k!$. Note that $n!/(n-k)!$ is a product of $k$ terms of the form $n-j$, with $j$ ranging from $0$ to $k-1$. Similarly, the denominator $n^k$ is a product of $k$ copies of $n$. Match these up to obtain a product of $k$ ratios, each one of which tends to $1$ as $n\to\infty$, hence their product also tends to $1$, leaving $\frac1{k!}$.

Remember that we are treating $m$ as fixed throughout this step, so it is legitimate to take the limit (as $n\to\infty$) of the rightmost sum in (1) term by term. Likewise, it is legitimate to take the limit of the product (2) term by term, since you have at most $m$ factors in (2) that involve $n$.

Comment: Could you prove the last fact (or give some hints on how to?)? I attempted to prove it by induction but I failed.

Comment: I've edited my answer to expand on the last step.

Answer (score 2):

Define
$$ s_m(z) = \sum_{j=0}^m \frac{z^j}{j!}, t_m(z) = \left(1 + \frac{z}{m}\right)^m
$$
We wish to show that $\lim_{j \to \infty} s_m(z) = \lim_{j \to \infty} t_m(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. By the Binomial Theorem,
$$\begin{align*}
t_m(z) &= \sum_{j=0}^m \binom m j 1^{m-j} \left(\frac z m\right)^j
= \sum_{j=0}^m \frac{m!}{j!(m-j)!} \frac{z^j}{m^j} \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^m \frac{m!}{m^j(m-j)!} \frac{z^j}{j!} \leq s_m(z)
\end{align*}$$
Since $m!/(m^j(m-j)!) \leq 1$. Hence $\limsup_{m \to \infty} t_m(z) \leq \limsup_{m \to \infty} s_m(z)$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\limsup s_m(z) =\exp z$ *follows from Cauchy-Hadamard*? You're only  talking about the radius of convergence? (As $s_m(z) \to \exp z$ is the usual definition of $\exp$).

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Yes. I will make it clear

Answer (score 1):

The hard part of the proof
seems to be 
to show that
if $k < n$
then
$\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac j n\right) 
=1
$.

I would do it
using this lemma:

If 
$x_k > 0$
and
$\sum_{k=1}^n x_k
< 1
$,
then
$\prod_{i=1}^k (1-x_i)
\ge 1-\sum_{i=1}^k x_i
$
for
$1 \le k \le n
$.

The proof, of course,
is by induction.

It is true for $k=1$.

If it true for $k$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
\prod_{i=1}^{k+1} (1-x_i)
&=(1-x_{k+1})\prod_{i=1}^{k} (1-x_i)\\
&\ge (1-x_{k+1})(1-\sum_{i=1}^{k} x_i)\\
&=1- \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} x_i +x_{k+1}\sum_{i=1}^{k} x_i\\
&\ge 1- \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} x_i \\
\end{array}
$

Now consider
$p(k, n)
= \prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac j n\right) 
$.

If
$\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac j n
< 1
$,
we can apply the lemma.
But this is equivalent to
$n > \frac{k(k-1)}{2}
$,
which is certainly true
for
$n > k^2
$.

The next step
is to make the product
arbitrarily close to $1$
by making $n$ even larger.

If $n > k^2$,

$\begin{array}\\
p(k, n)
&=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac j n\right)\\
&\ge 1-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(\frac j n\right)\\
&\ge 1-\frac{k(k-1)}{2n}\\
&\gt 1-\frac{k^2}{n}\\
\end{array}
$

So if we choose
$n > k^3$,
$p(k, n)
\gt 1-\frac{(n^{1/3})^2}{n}
= 1-\frac1{n^{1/3}}
$
and we can make this
arbitrarily close to $1$
by making $n$ large enough.