# How to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^{1/n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} 1/k!$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $e_n$ be $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}$.
Let $E_n$ be $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}$.
Suppose the convergence of $(e_n)$ and $(E_n)$ are established and let $e =lim_{n\to\infty}(e_n)$.

By Binomial Theorem,
$$e_n = 1+1+\frac{1}{2!}(1-\frac{1}{n})+\ldots+\frac{1}{n!}(1-\frac{1}{n})(1-\frac{2}{n})\ldots(1-\frac{n-1}{n})$$
Let $\epsilon >0$.
Since $e =lim_{n\to\infty}(e_n)$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for each $n\ge N$, $|e_n-e| < \epsilon /2$.  I was trying to show that there exists $N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|E_n-e_n| < \epsilon /2$, but I failed.

How to prove that the two sequences converge to the same limit?

Comment: Make it $\sum_{k=0}^\infty 1/k!$

Comment: Sorry about the typos.  I have edited that.

Comment: Apply the dominated convergence theorem: the $k$th term is less than $\frac{1}{k!}$, and has a limit of $\frac{1}{k!}$.

Comment: Or, it looks like the monotone convergence theorem would also work.

Comment: I posted a new answer to the linked question, based on the dominated convergence theorem argument.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments, through the link given, I have found another link that I think I could understand the answer using what I have learnt so far, [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1712372/refining-rudins-proof-of-lim-left-1-frac-1-n-rightn-lim-sum-k-1n?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3):

Using [Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) on $$\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)^n$$

the $r(0\le r\le n)$th term $$T_{r+1}=\dfrac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-r+1)}{r!n^r}=\dfrac1{r!}\prod_{u=0}^{r-1}\left(1-\dfrac un\right)$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}T_{r+1}=?$$

Comment: This lacks rigor inasmuch as you have not shown that $$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}&=1+\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \prod_{\ell=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac\ell n\right) \frac{1}{k!}\\\\&=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lim_{n\to \infty}\prod_{\ell=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac\ell n\right) \frac{1}{k!}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for the hints. I think I have found an answer here, [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1712372/refining-rudins-proof-of-lim-left-1-frac-1-n-rightn-lim-sum-k-1n?noredirect=1&lq=1)