# Rudin 3.31 Why does the limit equal e?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, eulers-number-e

In the following theorem, why does the limit end up being e from (14) and (15)? I thought we would need to show that the limsup and the liminf are equal to e for the limit to equal e?

[image]

Comment: You might find [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1712372/refining-rudins-proof-of-lim-left-1-frac-1-n-rightn-lim-sum-k-1n/1712397#1712397) helpful. In that answer, I fill in the missing details of Rudin's rather cryptic proof of this theorem. In particular, see the start of my answer, where I say "the structure of this proof is..."

Comment: Many (including myself) take the first line as the *definition* of $e$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since$$e\leqslant\liminf\nolimits_nt_n\leqslant\limsup\nolimits_nt_n\leqslant e,$$we have$$e=\liminf\nolimits_nt_n=\limsup\nolimits_nt_n,$$which is the same thing as asserting that $e=\lim_nt_n$.