# Induction problem, how to prove the final step

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$\displaystyle\sqrt[n]{n!}\leq\frac{n+1}{2}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$

Comment: perhaps you could show some of your work?

Comment: This is the AM>GM inequality applied on the first $n$ natural numbers. Do you have to use induction?

Comment: It would be clearer what you are asking if you showed what "final step" comes about in this "Induction problem".

Answer (score 2):

If $m!\le\left(\dfrac{m+1}2\right)^m$

$(m+1)!=(m+1)\cdot m!\le(m+1)\cdot\left(\dfrac{m+1}2\right)^m$

It is sufficient to show $$(m+1)\cdot\left(\dfrac{m+1}2\right)^m\le\left(\dfrac{m+2}2\right)^{m+1}\iff\left(1+\dfrac1{m+1}\right)^{m+1}\ge2$$

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254335/prove-that-5-2-e-3/254339#254339

Comment: Thanks. Oh gosh. Always a small trick. This is I did.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(1+\dfrac1{m+1}\right)^{m+1}\ge2$$ to show easily take $n=m+1$ 
so $$\left(1+\dfrac1{n}\right)^{n}\ge2\\
\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ 0\end{array}\right)1^n\dfrac 1n^0+
\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ 1\end{array}\right)1^{n-1}\dfrac 1n^1+
\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ 2\end{array}\right)1^{n-2}\dfrac 1n^2+...=\\
1+n.1^{n-1}.\dfrac 1n+\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}.1^{n-2}.\dfrac{1}{n^2}+...=\\
1+1+\dfrac{n-1}{2n}+...\geq2$$